# Intersection of a Sylow $p$-subgroup and a $p$-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group, $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$. Show that $$H \cap N_{G}(P)=H \cap P.$$

I try to use the conjugate relation and try to emulate the proof of the intersection of $P$ Sylow subgroup and a normal subgroup but I'm not sure.

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: The normalizer contains $P$, and $P$ contains every $p$-subgroup contained in $N_G(P)$, because $P$ is normal in $N_G(P)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H \cap N_G(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, but $P$ is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, hence $H \cap N_G(P) \subseteq H \cap P$. The reverse inclusion is obvious.